# How can to test Fragment with Espresso 2?

Tags: android, testing, android-fragments, android-espresso

I have android-project, in it I have one MainActivity (`extends ActionBarActivity`) and some MyFragments (`extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). In my project: first start: MainActivity, second start: MyFragment1 (for log in), next start: MyFragment2 (after log in, with list some params). And you cannot see MyFragment2 (with some list), before log in by MyFragment1.

How can I to test MyFragment2 without log in MyFragment1? By Espresso 2?
(https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/)
Now - If I at first to test MyFragment1, I can to test MyFragment2, But If  I want to test just MyFragment2.. Help me, please.

Comment: Hi Paushchyk Julia, have you got the solution?